# How to fix this minor color glitch when toggling dark mode in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Here's the video first:
https://youtube.com/shorts/7hzPLolOjIY?feature=share

As you see in the video, border under the AppBar and on top of the BottomNavigationBar changes weirdly. I've used slow animations for the video and seems like it hits black or white before changing between those two colors.

Code that I'm using:

```
return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border(
      top: BorderSide(
        color: context.read<ThemeNotifier>().getDarkmode()
            ? const Color(0xFF404040)
            : const Color(0xFFECEEF1),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  child: BottomNavigationBar(
    elevation: 0,
    currentIndex: index,
    onTap: onTap,
```

And code for the AppBar.

```
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const CustomAppBar({super.key, this.title, this.showActions = false});

  final String? title;
  final bool showActions;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      leading: Navigator.of(context).canPop()
          ? IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                Iconography.arrowLeft,
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground,
                height: Iconography.m,
                width: Iconography.m,
              ),
            )
          : null,
      elevation: 0,
      centerTitle: true,
      title: title == null
          ? SvgPicture.asset(
              Theme.of(context).isDark ? Logo.dark : Logo.light,
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
            )
          : Text(
              title!,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
            ),
      actions: showActions
          ? [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: null,
                icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  Iconography.calendar,
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground,
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: null,
                icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  Iconography.search,
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground,
                ),
              ),
            ]
          : null,
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(44);
}
```

build method of App widget.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeNotifier = Provider.of<ThemeNotifier>(context);

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      useInheritedMediaQuery: true,
      builder: DevicePreview.appBuilder,
      locale: DevicePreview.locale(context),
      themeMode: themeNotifier.getDarkmode() ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
      theme: Platform.isIOS
          ? Config.getFlavor().lightTheme.copyWith(
                splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
                highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                splashColor: Colors.transparent,
              )
          : Config.getFlavor().lightTheme,
      darkTheme: Platform.isIOS
          ? Config.getFlavor().darkTheme?.copyWith(
                splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
                highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                splashColor: Colors.transparent,
              )
          : Config.getFlavor().darkTheme,
      localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
      supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
      home: const CounterPage(),
    );
  }
```

**Update:**

I realized maybe toggling colors like that causes that sharp switch and give colors from theme instead. But still no luck.

```
 return AppBar(
      shape: Border(
        bottom: BorderSide(
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.tertiary,
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Can you post the code for AppBar?

Comment: can you check in the release build/mode and see if it's still there?

Comment: I confirm it's also in release.

Comment: That's normal because that's the device at milliseconds,
will that happen on your device because you don't do it perfectly (Change them) I suggested you use [flutter_phoenix](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phoenix) that's will make it easy and more Efficient the package will rebuild the whole app widgets and that will make it too easy to the device,
I hope this helped you.

Comment: Why it's normal? Every part of the app can change smoothly from dark mode to light mode. Just those dividers hit other colors before switching.

Comment: Will I give an advice and it's work so well for me, I think that's was programmings always like, Also Dislike is not good way to disagree with me.

Comment: Unfortunately, you didn't answer the question. I'm just switching colors based on theme preferences, your answer is, "it's normal, you don't do it perfectly, here's a random package". Before giving out advice, can you answer how helpful to answer it with "it's normal"? What exactly I'm not doing it perfectly? What's the benefit of using some sort of restarting package when just toggling theme?

Comment: I suspect thats' because you are using the colors directly and not using the ```theme``` colors, instead of setting the color directly, try using theme.of(context) with a color set from color theme. The system will animate between colors, but in your case you're setting the color directly.

Comment: @danypata thank you, that's very good idea. I've actually tried this but no luck, pasting on the initial post now.

Comment: @mirkancal One more question ? Is this glitch still present if you switch the system theme ? Or it's happening only if you switch it from the app side ? I did a dummy test with your colors and i i switch the system theme it doesn't have the glitch.

Comment: @danypata I think when you chance system theme on iPhone, you don't see the app.

Comment: @mirkancal I've tested on simulator and there's a shortcut for that :)) so you can see the app.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `context.read<ThemeNotifier>().getDarkmode()` why not let trigger the theme change in your material app using theme mode, then in your code, set color based on the current brightness.
In this way the border only rebuilds when the theme is passed down the context context.

```
 MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: Strings.appTitle,
      theme: AppTheme().light,
      themeMode: context.watch<ThemeNotifier>().getDarkmode() ? ThemeMode.dark: ThemeMode.light,
      darkTheme: AppTheme().dark,
      color: AppTheme().primary,
```

then

```
Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark
        ? const Color(0xFF404040)
        : const Color(0xFFECEEF1),
```

Comment: I was using Provider.of in materialapp, I'm pasting that part to the initial post now. context.watch is also returning provider.of

Comment: My solution is that you should depend on the brightness that exists in the theme, not the one in your Theme notifier class, let the theme be switched from themeMode in your MaterialApp

Comment: in this way your the border only changes color when the new theme is passed down the flutter tree.

Comment: So you are saying, instead of giving ThemeColor or using ?: with ThemeNotifier, use ?: with Theme.of(context).brightness? Tried that just now, not working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use animated container, here an example:

```
return AnimatedContainer(
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
  border: Border(
    top: BorderSide(
      color: context.read<ThemeNotifier>().getDarkmode()
      ? const Color(0xFF404040)
      : const Color(0xFFECEEF1),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  child: BottomNavigationBar(
    elevation: 0,
    currentIndex: index,
    onTap: onTap,
  ),
);
```

Comment: Is it possible to apply it for whole page?